# .Net Core TestClient cannot post with parameters

Tags: integration

I am creating Web API integration test with MSTest Test Server. I can request data. However when I post with data, request routed to Test Server without parameters. Below is my codes, where I am wrong?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected async Task TestDataInitializeAsync()
    {
        _factory = new WebApplicationFactory<MyWebApi.Startup>();
        _client = _factory.CreateClient();

        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
         new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", ".NET Foundation Repository Reporter");
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "userABC"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password","password123")
        });

        var response = await _client.PostAsync("/account/login", content);
     }
```

Here is my Controller method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Account controller ASP.NET identity authentication
/// </summary>
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<object> Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, false, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var appUser = _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(r => r.UserName == userName);
                return GenerateJwtToken(userName, appUser);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "No user found! Please check user name and password." });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    } 
 }
```

}

Parameters, **username** and **password** always null.

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason after read [ASP.NET Core 2.2 Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) carefully. The key point is **[ApiController]** attribute. It does not related with **TestClient**.

In .NET Core 2.2, if you put **[ApiController]** attribute in Class level or Assembly level, .NET Core framework will do parameter binding automatically. We no need to define as **[FromBody]** in front of the object parameters for complex type. However, for simple type such as int, string, bool, we need to put **[FromBody]**, **[FromForm]**, **[FromQuery]**, **[FromHeader]**, **[FromRoute]**, **[FromServices]**, accordingly.

In my case, I just put **[FromFrom]** attributes in front of two simple type parameters as below and problem was solved.

```
    <summary>
    /// To log-in to the system by using userName and password.
    /// If authentication is successed, bearer token will response from server.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    /// <returns>Bearer Token</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// </remarks>
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<object> Login([FromForm] string userName, [FromForm] string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, false, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var appUser = _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(r => r.UserName == userName);
                return GenerateJwtToken(userName, appUser);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "No user found! Please check user name and password." });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should edit your controller's action to get post parameters from your request's body using `FromBody` :

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("login")]
public async Task<object> Login([FromBody]LoginVm model)
{
   ...
}
```

With the `LoginVm` class containing Username and Password as string properties.

Hope it helps.

Comment: no. It is not working. I don't want to create a model as well.